# Alter table to add a primary key with using index tablespace and defer

Tags: sql, oracle, primary-key

I am trying to add a primary key into a table with using index tablespace and deferrable options, but I am getting an error. I am trying the following query:

```
ALTER TABLE  orders ADD CONSTRAINT ORD_ID_PK PRIMARY KEY(ord_id) 
USING INDEX TABLESPACE INDX
DEFERRABLE INITIALLY IMMEDIATE NOVALIDATE;
```

returning the error:

```
ERROR at line 3:
ORA-01735: invalid ALTER TABLE option
```

I cannot figure out which part of the query is wrong or missing, could someone guide me?

Comment: Please edit your question and include the DDL for the ORDERS table. Do you have any other constraints on this table and if so, what are they? What is the datatype of `ORD_ID`?

Comment: should it be `DEFERRABLE INITIALLY IMMEDIATE ENABLE NOVALIDATE`